# Rails devise how to flip the flow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I was wondering how you flip the flow of a website.

Example:
Normally a visitor needs an user login to write a summary.
When the visitor come to the page and click create summary, are the visitor normally redirect to sign up page.

How to flip the flow. So you can write a summary without login. And when you click next, you need to login or create a user. User decides to create an user and the summary are created with an association or the user have a login and it also creates and association.

How to create this with devise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following approach:

After creating the summary, store its ID in a session variable. Then, when the user signs in, if any summary IDs are found in their session, associate them with the signed in user

For example:

```
class SummaryController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @summary = Summary.create!(params[:summary])
    unless user_signed_in?
      session[:anon_summary_ids] ||= []
      session[:anon_summary_ids] << @summary.id
      redirect_to(user_sign_in_path, :notice => "Thanks for the summary! Please sign in...")
    end
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  before_filter :associate_summaries, :if => [:user_signed_in?, :anon_summaries?]

  private

  def anon_summaries?
    session[:anon_summary_ids].try(:any?)
  end

  def associate_summaries
    Summary.where(:id => session[:anon_summary_ids], :user_id => nil).update_all(:user_id => current_user.id)
    session[:anon_summary_ids] = nil
  end
end
```